# How to switch on, off between $(document).on() & $("a").on() in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, onclicklistener

I am implementing extension to record all browser actions.
`$(document).on()` is working in few websites and `$("a").on()` is working in few websites. So i placed both in single file that is `dom.js`. As of now it is recording two actions. How to handle to record only one action?

Please help me.

```js
var bindEventToNewElement = function(e) {

    var target = $(e.target.tagName);

    $(target).off().on('click',function (e) {
        alert("target");
         if (e.target !== this) return;
        // e.stopPropagation();

        var content="";
        if($(this).text()!==undefined){

            content=$(this).text();

        }

        if(($(this).attr('href')=="")||($(this).attr('href')=="#")||($(this).attr('href')==null)) {

            sendmsg(getPath(this), "click",'',content,"link",traverseElement(this),window.location.href,getElementName(this));

        }else{

            sendmsg($(this).attr('href'), "redirect", '',content,"link",traverseElement(this),window.location.href,getElementName(this));

        }

        $(target).off();
      
        $(document).off('click','a');
        $(document).on('click','a');
        $("a").on('click');
    });

};

/**
 * DOMNodeInserted event for adding dynamic html content
 */
$(document).on('DOMNodeInserted','a',bindEventToNewElement);


/*

 * Event of clicking on anchor tag and attaching event to root level document

 */
$(document).on('click','a', function(obj) {

    if (obj.target !== this) return;
   // obj.stopPropagation();
    
    var content="";
    if($(this).text()!==undefined){

        content=$(this).text();

    }

    if(($(this).attr('href')=="")||($(this).attr('href')=="#")||($(this).attr('href')==null)) {

        sendmsg(getPath(this), "click",'',content,"link",traverseElement(this),window.location.href,getElementName(this));

    }else{

        sendmsg($(this).attr('href'), "redirect", '',content,"link",traverseElement(this),window.location.href,getElementName(this));

    }


});

/*

 * Event of clicking on anchor tag and attaching event handler directly to the DOM

 */
$("a").on('click',function(obj) {

    if (obj.target !== this) return;

    var content="";
    if($(this).text()!==undefined){

        content=$(this).text();

    }

    if(($(this).attr('href')=="")||($(this).attr('href')=="#")||($(this).attr('href')==null)) {

        sendmsg(getPath(this), "click",'',content,"link",traverseElement(this),window.location.href,getElementName(this));

    }else{

        sendmsg($(this).attr('href'), "redirect", '',content,"link",traverseElement(this),window.location.href,getElementName(this));

    }

     $(document).off('click','a');

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `//$("a").on('click');` comment out this one.

Comment: `$(document).on('click','a');` and `$("a").on('click');` don't do anything. Calling `.off()` doesn't temporarily turn off an existing event handler like turning off a light bulb, it *removes* the event handler, so you can't just turn it on again with `.on('click')`. (Just guessing at what you think that code does...)

Comment: yeah. the things is if it enters into document i want to $("a") is off. so that it will not go to $("a") and if it enters into $("a") first i have to off the document but we have to on again to work for other things. Am i right?

DomNodeInserted i am handling for dynamic added html elements

Comment: I did it. :) @nnnnnn